# PhpStorm is using Composer cache for interface declaration

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm I'm getting multiple declarations for interfaces but one appears to be a Composer cache. How do I remove this declaration?

[image]

Comment: Try removing the `/vendor/composer/a3a92c62` folder from an Include Path at File | Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Languages & Frameworks | PHP.

Comment: @Dmitrii Thanks for the reply, that sounds like it would work but I upgraded PHPStorm first and that also appeared to resolve it for some reason. Was previously using 2020.1 and now on 2020.3.3, oddly 2020.1 was working fine on that same project for a long while then suddenly it wasn't

Comment: @Neild Nand, happy to hear this works now :)